# What to use a Paper or a Card?

Tags: material-ui

I want to make a component as in the photo. Is there a difference in using a paper/card, if I don't need an card API, or using paper in this case "violates the semantics of material-ui"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0mLJ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paper component is mostly background of an application resembles the flat, opaque texture of a sheet of paper, and an application’s behavior mimics paper’s ability to be re-sized, shuffled, and bound together in multiple sheets.

The Card is are surfaces that display content and actions on a single topic.

So for you you should use a Card !

Like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
});

export default function MediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you put a Card on a Paper?

Comment: Because you have a library who handle already this so why do something already there ? Make the diff between a Paper and a Card first those two are not the same and not built for the same use cases. @ankush981